# Vuetify Form Validation - defining ES6 rules for matching inputs

Tags: validation, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a (Vuetify) form with an email input that uses ES6 & regex to check if it's a valid email. How would I set up another `emailConfirmationRules` ruleset to check if the `emailConfirmation` input matches the `email` input?

```
<template>
  <v-form v-model="valid">
       <v-text-field label="Email Address"
            v-model="email" 
            :rules="emailRules"
            required></v-text-field>

       <v-text-field label="Confirm Email Address"
            v-model="emailConfirmation" 
            :rules="emailConfirmationRules"
            required></v-text-field>
   </v-form>
 <template>

export default {
    data () {
      return {
         valid: false,
         email: '',
         emailConfirmation: '',
         emailRules: [
             (v) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
             (v) => /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
        ],
        emailConfirmationRules: [
            (v) => !!v || 'Confirmation E-mail is required',
        ]   (v) => ??? || 'Confirmation E-mail does not match'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can accomplish the same with a computed rule.

```
computed: {
    emailConfirmationRules() {
      return [
        () => (this.email === this.emailToMatch) || 'E-mail must match',
        v => !!v || 'Confirmation E-mail is required'
      ];
    },
}
```

Comment: any way to make it pristine again.? my form is reusable, but when use this rules it always show error for the second form and other form

Answer (score 18):

Rules are not the proper way of handling field confirmation.
*emailConfirmationRules* are triggered only when *emailConfirmation* changes, but if you change *email* again, your fields won't match anymore without any break of rules.

You have to handle this manually:

```js
methods: {
  emailMatchError () { 
    return (this.email === this.emailConfirmation) ? '' : 'Email must match'
  }
}
```

```html
<v-text-field v-model='emailConfirmation' :error-messages='emailMatchError()'></v-text-field>
```

There may be an alternative way of doing this with vee-validate too.

Comment: It's the good way but the best is to put this method inside computed

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thanks! Because like you said, even if rules are computed properties, they are not reactive to changes in other components (fields).

Answer (score 1):

```
  emailConfirmationRules: [
    (v) => !!v || 'Confirmation E-mail is required',
    (v) => v == this.email || 'E-mail must match'
  ],
```

Comment: I think i have updated something, the solution worked all the time but now i also get undefined. But not the "this". just the value is always undefined. The property itself has the correct value. I think I need to change my way to validate. Maybe vee-validate

Comment: Wrong answer. Please see Eiji Shinjo's answer below.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm getting the following error: `Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: _this is undefined"`

Comment: This is WRONG answer. Rule-functions are called without context (see https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/e60cf638dfd671af6fc8fa4ff01fe7addc914f9c/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/validatable/index.ts#L239)

Comment: `this` is not available in an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

```
  <template>   
    <v-text-field
      v-model="employee.email"
      :rules="emailRules"
      required
      validate-on-blur
      />
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
    emailRules: [
        v => !!v || "E-mail is required",
        v =>
          /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) ||
          "E-mail must be valid"
      ],
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883995/9169379

```html
<template>
  <v-input  v-model="firstPassword" />
  <v-input :rules=[rules.equals(firstPassword)] v-model="secondPassword" />
</template>

<script>    
  data() {
  firstPassword: '',
  secondPassword: '',
    rules: {
      equals(otherFieldValue) {
        return v =>  v === otherFieldValue || 'Not equals';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```