Rule of v-textfield cannot find an element declared in data
I'm using Vue3 and Vuetify and, while making the rule for the v-textfield of the confirm password field, I got this error:
I tried to compare the values of the password field and the one of the confirm password field, both associeted to the v-textfield with the v-model, but in the confirm password rule the variable of the password results undefined.
Here's the source.

Data whit rules and variables:
data: () => ({
  // Credentials
  username: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: '',

  passwordRules: [
    (value) => {
      if (value?.trim().length > 0) return true
      else return 'Password is required.'
    },
  ],
  confirmPasswordRules: [
    (value) => {
      if (value?.trim().length > 0) {
        // TODO: ERROR (this.password is undefined)
        if(value === this.password) {
          return true
        }
        else return 'Passwords do not match.'
      }
      else return 'Confirm password is required.'
    },
  ],
}),

The error appears all the times that I write a character in the v-textfield, since it's in the rule:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')
    at confirmPasswordRules

Thanks!

Long time no see that syntax but can you try with data() { rather than data: () => ({ here? Because this is Options API I suppose? Even tho after a read through the documentation looks like it's their syntax. Anyway, what about those passwordRules and confirmPasswordRules being in data? They should be in methods or computed, depending on how the API of the text field wants it. Because data is not meant to be updated down the road but to be updated with a side-effect. My point is mostly in the 2 most upvotes answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47213703/8816585

I tried with data() { and return since yes, it's Option API, and then it worked. Probably a mistake caused by the ide autocomplete tool, thank you. I've understand what you mean with the rules in data, thanks for the hint!

It's a different syntax but doesn't mean exactly the same. It's confusing because Vuetify uses that syntax quite a lot...

OP was writing his data key as
data: () => ({

which is not the proper syntax for the usual
data() {

It indeed doesn't have the same meaning when it comes down to the usage of this.
